# Why does R require a return inside of {} when using inside of with statement?

Tags: r

I could not find a reason why the code below would not work.

```
with(df, {a<-plot(x,y) b<-lines(x1,x2)})
```

Then I found some examples that used the following syntax.

```
with(df, {a<-plot(x,y) 
          b<-lines(x1,x2)})
```

When I used the second syntax I received no errors. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm guessing `with(df, {a<-plot(x,y); b<-lines(x1,x2)})` would also work. You need to separate the two commands you want to run. If you put them on one line, use a semicolon to separate them. Otherwise, the newline character will tell R they are separate statements.

Comment: I don't really understand how the question title and the body of the question are related.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#R-commands_003b-case-sensitivity-etc) section 1.8

> Commands are separated either by a semi-colon (‘;’), or by a newline.
>   Elementary commands can be grouped together into one compound
>   expression by braces (‘{’ and ‘}’).

Below codes are equivalent

```
with(df1, {a<-plot(x,y) ; b<-lines(x1,x2)}) 

with(df1, {a<-plot(x,y)
           b<-lines(x1,x2)})
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want two commands on the same line, separate them with a semicolon

```
with(df, {a<-plot(x,y); b<-lines(x1,x2)})
```

This isn't unique to`with` or `{}`. You can't just do

```
a <-5   b<-3   a+b   # syntax error if on the same line.
```

in R and have it run. You either need semicolons or new line characters between separate statements that you want R to run.